# How to save PDFs in SQL database using iTextSharp

Tags: sql-server-2008, itext

I am creating a PDF file using ITextSharp... Right now I am creating PDFs in one folder in system but I want store the PDFs in SQL table rather than in file system. Please help how to save pdfs in SQL database while creating pdfs using iTextSharp.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with iTextSharp, see this question for storing files in a database: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2121441/231316